# Optically access a single valley in indirect semicondutors

Tags: electronic-band-theory

An indirect semicondutor has an energetic minimum of its band structure at a point different from the $\Gamma$ point. But, there are multiple of them. Silicon for example has its band minimum at the six-fold degenerate $\Delta$ point. If I optically excite the semiconductor, I assume that the carriers would scatter simultaneously to all of the six valleys. Is that correct? And is there a way to only excite a single valley?